# PLINK and removing parts of the data

Tags: plink

I have a file of SNPs that was processed using [PLINK](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2). I have a list of several thousands SNPs. In the file they are assigned one of NA, 0, 1, or 2. I want to remove the list of SNPs that have an NA, i.e. they are monomorphic. The problem is that the file lists all of the multiple thousands of SNPs in order and then lists their respective values after that in one line separated by spaces. It is very hard to see what values correspond to which SNP based on manual inspection.

Is there an easy method to remove the monomorphic SNPs from the file using PLINK? Or is this best done using Python?

Comment: Thought he said plinq for a sec!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found it out yet, you can remove monomorphic SNPs using `PLINK --maf`.

Remove monomorphic SNPs in the dataset (those with a MAF = 0.0) 
http://www.shapeit.fr/pages/pedmap.html

Answer (score 1):

Erm, wouldn't `NA` mean that some snps are missing data values? To remove these, you should use the `--geno` command. To quote the [docs](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2/filter#missing):

> --geno filters out all variants with missing call rates exceeding the provided value (default 0.1) to be removed

The `--maf` command does remove monomorphic snps, however. Setting the --maf slightly above 0 might be wise, because if an allele is found at a very low frequency it is likely to represent genotyping error.

All in all, you might want to insert a quality-control of the following type into your plink command:

```
--geno 0.03 --hwe 0.00001 --maf 0.00001
```

(`hwe` is just the regular Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium).